# Filter a column by multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm new at Python and I want to filter rows by multiple column values.
The name of my dataframe is `df`, the column name is `values` and I want to filter this column by the following values:

```
2, 4, 5, 9
```

My dataframe is like this:

```
name value
Jon    4
Ron    5
Paul   10
Max    3
```

So grateful,
Henrique.

Comment: Start by seeing if this question has been asked already (you can use the search box above or simply google the question).  Then, if it hasn't, read the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to format a question.  This will show you how to include code and data in a question.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do this:

```py
df[(df["value"]==2) | (df["value"]==4) | (df["value"]==5) | (df["value"]==9)]
```

OR

```py
numbers = [2, 4, 5, 9]
df[df["value"].isin(numbers)]
```

Answer (score 0):

##### 1. For filtering single column you can use: `df.loc[df['column_name'] == some_value]`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': 'foo bar foo bar foo bar foo foo'.split(),
                   'B': 'one one two three two two one three'.split(),
                   'C': np.random.randint(3, size=8), 'D':np.random.randint(6, size=8)})
df
#returns
#     A      B  C  D
#0  foo    one  1  0
#1  bar    one  1  4
#2  foo    two  0  0
#3  bar  three  2  5
#4  foo    two  0  2
#5  bar    two  2  4
#6  foo    one  1  5
#7  foo  three  1  0

df_filtered = df.loc[df['C'] == 1] 

df_filtered #gives:
#     A      B  C  D
#0  foo    one  1  0
#1  bar    one  1  4
#6  foo    one  1  5
#7  foo  three  1  0
```

##### 2. For filtering with more values of single column you can use the '|' operator (for multiple conditions): `df.loc[(df['column_name'] >= A) | (df['column_name'] <= B)]`.

*since you mention filter by single column values (the name of the single column you call 'values' which has different values 2, 4, 5, 9 for example), you can use this approach:*

```
df_filtered = df.loc[(df['C'] == 1)| (df['C'] == 2)] 

df_filtered #returns:

#     A      B  C  D
#0  foo    one  1  0
#1  bar    one  2  1
#2  foo    two  1  1
#3  bar  three  2  2
#4  foo    two  1  1
#5  bar    two  2  2
#6  foo    one  2  2
```

##### 3. You can even filter by multiple column values using the same approch:

```
df_filtered = df.loc[(df['C'] == 1)| (df['D'] == 2)]

df_filtered  #gives:

#     A      B  C  D
#0  foo    one  1  0
#2  foo    two  1  1
#3  bar  three  2  2
#4  foo    two  1  1
#5  bar    two  2  2
#6  foo    one  2  2
# note that this time we filter all the df values corresponding to columns C == 1 & D == 2
```